# Tricks to compute automorphism groups quickly

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

To try getting better understanding of automorphism groups, i tried computing those of products of cyclic groups. For example to compute $\text{Aut}(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 4)$, i could use the generators $((1,0), (0,1))$ and check if the map induced by sending those to a different set of generators is an automorphism. Theres a lot of sets of generators however so this is tedious. What are some tricks to compute stuff like this faster?

Comment: For groups of the form $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, where $m|n$ (as is the case here, with $n=0$ and $m=4$), you can use the same type of argument as used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147155/742).

Comment: Every automorphism preserves orders of elements. There are not many order $4$ elements in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z_4$. In general look for properties preserved by any automorphism.

Comment: @markvs Yes im actually aware of this and forgot to write in question, there are still a lot of possibilities even with that.

Comment: The possibilities are easy to enumerate. $(0,1)$ must map to $(0,1)$ or $(0,-1)$, and $(1,0)$ must map to $(1,t)$ or $(-1,t)$ for some $t$ with $0 \le t \le 3$.

Comment: @CcVHKakalLLOOPPOkKkkKk: There are exactly $16$ automorphisms. A lot for some people.